# Alt codes in batch a file

Tags: batch-file

According to some people (And I have used it before and it worked.) you can use alt codes in batch like this:

```
 ░ = °
 ▒ = ±
 ▓ = ²
```

But it stopped working? The symbols come out with a lot of spam. Help?

Edit:

Here is how you "get the alt code in" [{link}](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbWDiXUiWhM)

And a image on what the alt symbols look like:

[image]

It add the first symbol.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean by "Use them like this." How exactly are you using them? For a slightly more graphical console? This might be a time to attach images (both what you expect and what you're getting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open up notepad and click on "Encoding" and click on "Convert to ASCII" some symbols will be lost but °±² wont display a T symbol before it

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

- Start the command prompt (CMD)
- Type: `echo/░>"%userprofile%\Desktop\File.txt"`
- The file File.txt should appear on your desktop.
- Open File.txt, and the content of this file, is the character you should use. (° in this case)
- After you get the special  character from File.txt, you can use it in your batch file:
- `echo/°`

Comment: It echos what you see in the pic.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Character Map and copy every character.
After that, make a batch file and just paste it in like this:

```
ECHO ÇüéâäàåçêëèïîìÄÅÉæÆôöòûùÿÖÜø£Ø×ƒáíóúñÑªº¿®¬½¼¡«»░▒▓│┤ÁÂÀ©╣║╗╝
ECHO ¢¥┐└┴┬├─┼ãÃ╚╔╩╦╠═╬¤ðÐÊËÈıÍÎÏ┘┌█▄¦Ì▀ÓßÔÒõÕµþÞÚÛÙýÝ¯´±‗¾¶§÷¸°¨·¹³²■
pause
```

Now, in the command line window you chould see that it echo's something else.

E.g. "É" in a batch-file, echo's "╔" in the command line window.

[image: A test I din on my computer.]

Comment: Yes and it puts the stuff be hide it like in the pic.